# How to keep checking all the time for internet connection in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, get

I've got an android application that depends on the internet to work. I need to find a way to keep checking all the time for internet existence to view the application .. otherwise, when there is no internet I should view a widget that says no internet connection.

I have tried the package [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)  but it is not working as expected as it only checks for the switch ( wifi -mobile data ) if it is on or off, not real internet.

I thought sending a get request to a website and analyzing the response status code would be a good idea for me. so here is what I tried :

**Check Connection Class**

```dart
class CheckConnectionService {
  Future<bool> checkConnection() async {
    int theCode = 0;
    Client client = Client();
    try {
      await client.get('http://www.google.com').then((value) {
        theCode = value.statusCode;
      });
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
      return false;
    }finally{
      client.close();
    }
    if (theCode == 200){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

then in my **main.dart** I've tried to use this check to be running all the time, here is my code:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool internetExists = true;

  Stream checkIfOnline() async* {
    await CheckConnectionService().checkConnection().then((check) {
      print(check);
    if (check){
      internetExists = true;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      internetExists = false;
      setState(() {});
    }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    checkIfOnline();
    if (!internetExists){
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'G-Attend',
          home: NoInternet(),
        );
    } else{
      return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Anton',
          primaryColor: Hexcolor('#691b99'),
          primaryColorLight: Hexcolor('#9b4dcb'),
          primaryColorDark: Hexcolor('#37006a'),
          secondaryHeaderColor: Hexcolor('#60C0D5'),
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/splash',
        routes: {
          '/splash': (context) => SplashScreen(),
          '/login': (context) => Login(),
          '/index': (context) => Index(),
          '/settings': (context) => Settings(),
          '/requests': (context) => Requests(),
          '/add_request': (context) => AddRequest(),
          '/request_comments': (context) => RequestComments(),
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

What happens that it is always showing the part where the internet should be working, even when there is no real internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the internet connection you can use the package [`data_connection_checker`](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker):

```
bool hasConnection = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
    setState(() {
      switch(status){
        case DataConnectionStatus.connected:
          hasConnection = true;
          break;
        case DataConnectionStatus.disconnected:
          hasConnection = false;
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I usually go to `External Libraries` > `data_connection_checker-version`

And in the dart file i change the DEFAULT_INTERNAL to 1, for verification to happen every 1 second:

```
static const Duration DEFAULT_INTERVAL = const Duration(seconds: 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below plugin to check and monitor connectivity

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/connectivity

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Got a new connectivity status!
  })
}

// Be sure to cancel subscription after you are done
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();

  subscription.cancel();
}
```

Comment: AS mentioned in the question, this is not a good solution as it doesn't really check for real internet .. also in the official documentation they say: `Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to the Internet. For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or a hotel WiFi with no access.`

Answer (score 0):

this the main example of connectivity plugin for new version

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// Sets a platform override for desktop to avoid exceptions. See
// https://flutter.dev/desktop#target-platform-override for more info.
void _enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop() {
  if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux)) {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  }
}

void main() {
  _enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _connectionStatus = 'Unknown';
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initConnectivity();
    _connectivitySubscription =
        _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initConnectivity() async {
    ConnectivityResult result;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) {
      return Future.value(null);
    }

    return _updateConnectionStatus(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Connectivity example app'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('Connection Status: $_connectionStatus')),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result.toString());
        break;
      default:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = 'Failed to get connectivity.');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of browser caching. I found that calling cloudflare servers produces a consistent result.